# Implementing multi tenancy on Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am planning to write a multi tenant aware application using Spring Data JPA as the persistent layer. However I'm not planning to keep separate databases per tenant rather all the data is in a single database. Following beans represent the Project entity and Tenant entity that I'm planning to implement. When fetching a project or fetching the list of all projects, I should be able to filter them according to a specific tenant. I know that I can easily do that by writing methods like bindByIdAndTenant_Id(int id, int id) but I'm worrying about the scalability of the solution. What I need is to have a method like findById(int id) and content will be automatically filtered by the tenant id that is fetched from a context. Is there a way I can do that in Spring Data JPA?

Project Entity

```
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_TENANT_IN_PROJ"))
private Tenant tenant;}
```

Tenant Entity

```
public class Tenant {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
int id;

@Column(name = "NAME", unique = true)
private String name;}
```

Comment: You can try using the multi-tenancy capabilities provided as extensions to some JPA implementations (see e.g. here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant and here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/multitenancy/MultiTenancy.html). At the time of writing, your use case (i.e. using discriminator columns) is not implemented in Hibernate. It is, however, supported in EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

There is (afaik) no such "out-of-the-box" mechanism. How should Spring know how a tenant is identified and what is important to separate the data. Maybe there is even some shared data between tenants so things get more complicated and it's on your own to do that.

I assume your data is accessed using a web layer  and you have to identify the tenant on every call. A "simple" path parameter or a header is (without any further validation) too easy to manipulate so maybe a token ([JWT](https://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html)) is a good alternative to store request based tenant information. Here is a [nice article](http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/Make-your-Spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/) about exactly that topic. [Another one](http://www.stuartingram.com/2016/10/02/spring-boot-schema-based-multi-tenancy/) is talking about pros and cons, especially related to differences in storage architecture.

Personally, I would tend to the "different databases" approach. It's easy to scale out and user data is separated properly. Also backup and restore mechanisms are possible for each tenant without affecting the other users. At least use different schemata for each tenant, but maybe that depends on the database and what exactly is meant by "schema".